# Create a duplicate row on top of Select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

table TEST

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | xyz |

In general i used to get records from below query
Select id,name from TEST.

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | xyz |

but now i want to create a duplicate for each row on top my select query

expected output: please suggest how can i achieve result like below

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | xyz |
| 2 | xyz |

Comment: `cross join ( select null as __i from dual connect by level < 3)`

Answer (score 1):

You may cross join your table with a sequence table containing how ever many copies you want.  Here is an example using an inline sequence table:

```sql
SELECT t1.id, t1.Name
FROM yourTable t1
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS seq FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 FROM dual
) t2
WHERE t2.seq <= 2
ORDER BY t1.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

To me, `UNION` (ALL) set operator seems to be quite simple.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME
---------- ----
         1 abc
         2 xyz
```

UNION ALL:

```
SQL> select * from test
  2  union all
  3  select * from test;

        ID NAME
---------- ----
         1 abc
         2 xyz
         1 abc
         2 xyz

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is using a self-join along with `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function such as

```sql
WITH t AS
(
 SELECT t1.id, t1.name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id ORDER BY 0) AS rn
   FROM test t1,
        test t2
)
SELECT id, name
  FROM t
 WHERE rn <= 2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=5b6f00c2a249d77b8f27cb5059f129d2)</kbd>

Comment: It will generate N^2 rows (N - number of rows in the table)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE table test(
id integer,
name VARCHAR2(4)
);

INSERT into test (id, name) VALUES (1,'ABC');

INSERT into test (id, name) VALUES (2,'XYZ');


 with data as (select level l from dual connect by level <= 2)
    select *
      from test, data
     order by id, l
   /
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option is LATERAL

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test 
 , LATERAL (
      SELECT id, name FROM DUAL
      union all
      SELECT id, name FROM DUAL
   ) t
```